# webpack 5 : uncaught run time error; Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

I am using a config-overrides.js file that looks like:

```
/* config-overrides.js */
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  console.log("React app rewired works!");

  //   // Add webpack aliases for Node.js modules
  //   config.resolve.alias = {
  //     ...config.resolve.alias,
  //     // Add alias for the process module to use a browser-compatible version
  //     "process": "process/browser",
  //     // Add more aliases as needed
  //   };
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
    })
  );
  // Set fallbacks for other Node.js modules
  config.resolve.fallback = {
    assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url/"),
    querystring: require.resolve("querystring-es3"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
    zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
    net: require.resolve("net-browserify"),
    tls: require.resolve("tls-browserify"),
    fs: false,
    async_hooks: false,
  };

  return config;
};
```

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "razorpay_integration",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "config": "^3.3.11",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "net-browserify": "^0.2.4",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "razorpay": "^2.9.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tls-browserify": "^0.2.2",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "vm-browserify": "^1.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

error:

> Uncaught runtime errors: × ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'prototype') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'prototype')
> at ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51923:45)
> at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167736:31)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167165:32)
> at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167394:21)
> at ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51191:11)
> at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167736:31)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167165:32)
> at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167394:21)
> at ./node_modules/express/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50528:18)
> at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167736:31)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167165:32)
> at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167394:21)
> at ./node_modules/net-browserify/api.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:72560:15)
> at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167736:31)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167165:32)
> at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167394:21)
> at ./node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:127051:11)
> at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167736:31)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167165:32)
> at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167394:21)
> at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:126979:5
> at module.exports (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143656:5)